# ubuntu 16.04 system logs is being written all the time

Tags: 16.04, log

My system writing logs all the time and as result, I have high CPU usage and the leak of hard disk space

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue?

In the system log I see the following:

[image]

Comment: Something on your system is failing, probably device `8086:9d15`,, and logging error messages so rapidly that `systemd-journald` can't keep up! Fix or Disconnect that device and the log will calm down

Comment: @waltinator How to find out what is the device [8086:9d15] ?

Comment: `lsusb`, `sudo lspci`, Link: https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086/9d15